# Capybara webkit ignore ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using datatables in my application , and the records are loaded to the table by ajax. Now I'm writing tests for the page of my datatable and have to wait untill the records are loaded. I configured capybara webkit and put js: true in my test. but when I run the test i get this error

```
Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

 ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/images/sort_both.png"
```

In my browser i checked the console , and I don't get this errors, all images are found.

this is my configuration of webkit

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.raise_javascript_errors = false
end
```

i'm using wait_for_ajax method

```
def wait_for_ajax
  Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
    loop do
      active = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active')
      break if active == 0
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my test

```
scenario 'check pending contributions', js: true do
    login_as analyst, scope: :analyst

    visit '/analyst/contributions'

    wait_for_ajax
    expect(page).to have_content "#{contribution.user_name}"
  end
```

And now I want to fix this routing error , or just ignore it because I just want to test the logic, not js errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error isn't a JS error, it's an error raised by your server when an asset is requested.  You can probably tell your test to ignore the error by setting `Capybara.raise_server_errors = false`, however the better solution would be to fix your asset pipeline so that all assets are getting correctly served in the test environment.  Odds are that you have previously precompiled the assets in the test environment and that a left over manifest file is preventing it from recompiling newly added assets.  You can fix that by running something like

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake assets:clobber
```

Additionally, assuming the `#{contribution.user_name}` text is being loaded via the ajax call there is no need for the `wait_for_ajax` method call since `have_content` will already wait/retry.

Comment: thanks for the answers , it solved my problem of ActionController::RoutingError, but my test it's not working. My table is not being populated/capybara not waiting in the test so it doesn't find "#{contribution.user_name}". But thanks for the nice and precise answer.

Comment: @MatheusMendes Your test not working is a different issue, you can try increasing `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` in case it's just not waiting long enough for the response.  More likely is that you haven't created the records to be returned in the tests (either via not doing or by using `let` which lazily creates `contribution` so it's not actually in the DB when you get the ajax results), or you haven't disabled transactional testing and setup database_cleaner so the records are actually available in both the test and app threads.  However, that really is a separate question from this one

Comment: Thanks for the response @thomas, I'm tested that the record is being created with using pry, I'm using let! which creates the records in the beginning. All my other tests are working so a think my transactional testing a database_cleaner are ok. Will post another question with more details, thanks.